# Are two buttons with similar appearance and text an accessibility concern?

Tags: buttons, accessibility

I'm inspired by this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386770/175002 but I've come across this elsewhere as well.

[image: the cookie form with the two 'accept' buttons side-by-side; 'Accept all cookies' and 'Accept only necessary'.]

The two buttons read:

1. Accept all cookies
2. Accept only necessary

I'm straining to remember if them both staying with the same word is an accessiblity concern for, say dyslexic users?

Comment: `Accept: [All cookies] [Only necessary]` "Accept" can be pulled out and given two options: "All cookies" and "Only necessary".

Answer (score 1):

It could be a **usability** issue for some users but it's not a [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) failure so it's not technically an **accessibility** issue.

I think the wording of the cookie dialog as currently implemented ("Accept all cookies" and "Necessary cookies only") alleviates the issue since the button labels are quite different, but I can see the point of the other posts on that thread of making the button labels more consistent with each other.

And there's a decent usability argument that both buttons should say "Accept".  The "Necessary cookies only" button **implies** that you are accepting but it'd be better if it explicitly said that.  Without being explicit, it could be confusing for some users on whether they're really accepting or not.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information regarding using two primary buttons on the same layout. Not any research or scientific justification.

In my opinion, this is weird and doesn't give the user enough information to make a selection. If it doesn't matter to you whether the user clicks one or two buttons, then why are you adding both?

As with all UX, the most important thing is to ask questions. Why do we need a second button? Which option is preferable for us and which one for the user? If we decide on this, then we can understand how best to show it to us. And if the user still shows good results after testing, then we can safely write an article "justification for using two primer buttons at the same time"))